# Laravel 5.7.28 Debug not setting off in live server [ APP_DEBUG = false ] not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have uploaded one laravel project to live server. I have set **APP_DEBUG=false**

But it still loading things into debug mode.

ie. Showign .env file output when we open in browser

Laravel version is 5.7.28

- .env ==> [ APP_DEBUG=false ] Done
- config/app.php  ==> 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),   DONE 
  Both above changes has been made but it still shoing all the output.

I don't have access to live server terminal to install any addition server. Can anyone helps me to find any other setting to prevent debug on in live server.

How to prevent debugging and direct access to file. 
Any suggestion or help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Showign .env file output when we open in browser"? Looks like a bug in your application

Comment: Thanks Haase. I mean direct access of all dot files including .ENV file. 
For example, If you type www.website/.env

Comment: Why do you place `.env` in some directory that is accesible? Usually, you should place it outside the document root

Comment: I have no idea how to configure .env outside root in laravel. Laravel setup comes default as .env on root folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally to stop debug mode in laravel following should work.

- .env ==> [ APP_DEBUG=false ]
- config/app.php ==> 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

---

You said you cannot access terminal. Is it require for php artisan command ??

For that you can use route call to execute laravel command.

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "Cache is cleared";
});
```

---

You said you want to prevent direct access of file.

Generally into google you can easily search for websites which have .env files. And direct access are generally open.

Do following changes into .htaccess file.

```
# To Disable index view
Options -Indexes

# To Hide a .env file
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# To Hide all .(DOT) files
<FilesMatch "^\.(.+)$">
   order deny,allow
   deny from all 
   allow from 127.0.0.1  
</FilesMatch>
```